# Changing the contents of child processes in c program.

Tags: c, linux, child-process

I am pretty new to both linux and c programming. I need to write a c code that creates two child processes, which is fine, but I need to further change the code of one of the child processes to "the code of a ls-command", and the other to "the code of the ps-command".

This is supposed to be a really simple "pseudo-code", but I am not really sure if I understand the question, any tips?

Comment: Should you code the actual "commands" yourself? Or is is enough to [***exec***](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execvp.3.html)ute the existing commands?

Comment: Question says to create two child processes from your main process. You have to assign some duty to a process as well. In this case, duties for those two child processes is to perform "Is-command" and "ps_Command" functionalities.

Comment: You're describing what the `fork`/`exec` series of system calls does. Find the manual and start reading.

Comment: Are you familiar with the _[popen](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html)_ command?

Comment: Go through this article
http://www.csl.mtu.edu/cs4411.ck/www/NOTES/process/fork/create.html

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like `fork() + execve()` traditional combination. Call to `fork()` launches a new process which is a copy of the callee. And the consequent call to `execve("ls")` will replace the forked process with the *content* of the `ls` executable.

For more information see `man 2 fork` and `man 3 execv`.

Comment: Thank you for replying! I have this code so far:
` #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <unistd.h>
 
 int main() {
  printf("This program creates two child processes of the main process.");
  int child1;
  int child2;
  child1 = fork();
  if(child1 == 0) {
    execve("ls");
    exit(0);
  }
  child2 = fork();
  if(fork == 0) {
    execve("ps");
    exit(0);
  }
  }`


So to my understanding the child process' value is supposed to be 0. and execve is supposed to change the contents of the chil process. But I am not sure if I got this right.

Comment: Yes, it's more or less like you described. However, it would be better if you put this code snippet to your question instead of the comment because it's much easier to read than.